# How to write an Enterprise Library dataConfig.config file?

Tags: enterprise-library

I have 'inherited' a test harness application which uses Enterprise Library for its SQL data access. In the app.config file *(enterpriselibrary.configurationSettings)*, it references a "configurationSection" with a path to "dataConfig.config", which is encrypted. I would like to change the database connection properties, but EntLibConfig.exe will not open the dataConfig.config or app.config *(I have the FileKeyAlgorithmPairStorageProviderData file)*.

The test harness application runs, so its configured ok.

I can, in code, using (Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetConfiguration("dataConfiguration")) read the data configuration, and can navigate all the instances and connection strings *(security isn't an issue for this test harness)*. I can dump everything I need to a hand-crafted XML file *(using GetType().AssemblyQualifiedName to get the full name for the classes which read the config file)* and then change the app.config to read my new, unencrypted, xml dataConfig file.

All is fine, I can now change my database config settings.

However... given that ConfigurationManager.GetConfiguration("dataConfiguration") returns a fully populated instance of a DatabaseSettings object, is there not a method I can call which will write the XML file *(dataConfig.config)* for me ?

I appreciate that this is probably a really big hammer way to edit the data configuration, but after half a day of trying, I fell back on the old coding maxim... if you can't find the tool to do what you want, write your own !

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well... turns out that its not that hard.

I added a new "configurationSection" to my app.config *(dataConfiguration2)*, with encrypt set to false, with a path pointing to an new empty text file *(dataConfiguration.config2)*. I then copied my encrypted dataConfiguration details using the following code:

```
using Entlib = Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Configuration;
    :
DatabaseSettings settings = (DatabaseSettings)Entlib.ConfigurationManager.GetConfiguration("dataConfiguration");
Entlib.ConfigurationManager.WriteConfiguration("dataConfiguration2", settings);
```

...and it filled the empty file with the *(unencrypted)* configuration details.